# Missing nullptr for undeclared array element

Tags: c++, hashmap, nullptr

I am trying to make a basic HashMap.  I am checking to see if an element exists at an index before inserting it there.  When I insert my first element, it says that an element already exists at that position.  I have gone through the debugger, and all of my values are as expected, except for `map[hash]`.  I am anticipating a nullptr, but it is not coming.  `map[hash]` has the following value:

```
-       map[hash]   0xcdcdcdcd {key=??? value={...} next_element=??? }  HashElement *
```

Can someone please explain to me what I am misunderstanding here?  The unexpected result is on `line 21` of `HashMap.cpp`.  Here is the relevant code:

**HashMap.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

#include "HashElement.h"

class HashMap
{
private:
    HashElement **map;
    int size;
public:
    HashMap(int);
    ~HashMap();
    int GetHash(int);
    void Put(int, std::string);
};
```

**HashMap.cpp**

```
#include "HashMap.h"

#include <string>

HashMap::HashMap(int _size)
{
    size = _size;
    map = new HashElement*[size];
}

HashMap::~HashMap()
{
}

int HashMap::GetHash(int _key){
    return _key % size;
}

void HashMap::Put(int _key, std::string _value){
    int hash = GetHash(_key);
    if (!map[hash]){  //Anticipated to be nullptr on first Put, but it skips to else
        map[hash] = new HashElement(_key, _value);
    }
    else{
        HashElement *lastElement = map[hash];
        while (lastElement->next_element){
            lastElement = lastElement->next_element;
        }
        lastElement->next_element = new HashElement(_key, _value);
    }
}
```

**HashElement.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class HashElement
{
private:
    int key;
    std::string value;
public:
    HashElement(int, std::string);
    ~HashElement();
    HashElement *next_element;
    int get_key();
    std::string get_value();
};
```

**HashElement.cpp**

```
#include "HashElement.h"

HashElement::HashElement(int _key, std::string _value)
{
    key = _key;
    value = _value;
}

HashElement::~HashElement()
{
}

int HashElement::get_key(){
    return key;
}

std::string HashElement::get_value(){
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map[hash]` is not a `nullptr` because you haven't initialized it to such.

```
map = new HashElement*[size];
```

Each element in the `map` array will have a random value after that line.

To fix this and initialize all elements to be `nullptr`:

```
map = new HashElement*[size]();
                            ^^
```

Comment: I think you may be stalking me...following me around and answering all of my questions...dont stop :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
map = new HashElement*[size];
```

Here, you are instantiating an array of `size` pointers, on the heap. As I understand your question, you are assuming that all of the instantiated pointers, in this `new` array, will be `nullptr`.

That is not the case. For "plain old data", or `POD`, its contents are not initialized by default. You'll have to explicitly initialize them:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
    map[i]=0;
```

... in the constructor

Comment: Awesome! So initializing a HashElement to 0 makes it point to null?

Comment: null and 0 are the same thing. You can use the C++11 nullptr constant, if you prefer.